# How to compare log and exponential

Tags: inequality, logarithms

> $x^{1/3}$

> $　 (\log_{2}{x})^3$

How to compare them?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't have an algebraic solution. Only numerical solutions possible in this case.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am what trying ask. How I should compare these two number.

Comment: Why there is no algebraic solution ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "compare"?

Comment: FWIW, I just added a Newton's method solution to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there's no closed-form solution to
$$x^{1/3} = (\log_2 x)^3$$
in elementary functions, but it can be solved using the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Briefly, the Lambert W function is the (multi-branched) inverse function of
$$f(x) = xe^x$$
That is,
$$x = W_k(x)e^{W_k(x)}$$
When working with real numbers, we only need the $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$ branches.

This function is generally *not* found in the standard math libraries of common programming languages, but it is found in most advanced mathematics packages. You can approximate it in various ways, eg, [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Anyway, here's how to find the (real) solutions to your equation, assuming that you have some way of evaluating the Lambert W.

$$x^{1/3} = (\log_2 x)^3$$
$$x^{1/9} = \log_2 x$$
Let $x=u^9$
$$u = \log_2 u^9 = 9\log_2 u$$
$$2^u = u^9$$
$$u\log 2 = 9\log u$$
$$u = 9\log u / \log 2$$

The $\log u$ function grows slower than any power $u^n$ for $n>1$, so as Paul Rebenciuc mentioned at the end of his answer, for all sufficiently large $u$, $2^u > u^9$.

Let's pause for a moment to look at the graph of $y = 9\log x / \log 2$ and see where it crosses $y=x$.

[image: graph of 9log_2(x)]
Here are close-ups of the cross-over points.
[image: closeup 1 of graph] [image: closeup 2 of graph]

So we have solutions around $u = 1.087$ and $u = 51.069$.

Continuing,

$$u = 9\log u / \log 2$$
Let $m = 9 / \log 2$
$$u = m \log u$$
Let $u = e^{-v}$, so $\log u = -v$
$$e^{-v} = -mv$$
$$-1/m = ve^v$$
Now we can apply the Lambert W:
$$W(-1/m) = W(ve^v) = v$$

So now we can get $u$ from $u = e^{-v}$ and $x$ from $x=u^9$. As I mentioned earlier, we need to evaluate both the $W_{-1}$ and $W_0$ branches to get both solutions.

Here's a short Sage / Python script that performs this calculation. It also verifies that $u = -mv$.

#### Code

```
m = 9 / log(2)
for v in [lambert_w(i, -1/m) for i in (-1, 0)]:
    u = exp(-v)
    print("v", v.n())
    print("u", u.n(), "-mv", (-m*v).n())
    print("u^9", (u^9).n(), "2^u", (2^u).n())
    print()
```

#### Output

```
v -3.93318771959389
u 51.0695137614913 -mv 51.0695137614913
u^9 2.36295530009418e15 2^u 2.36295530009419e15

v -0.0837437490868883
u 1.08735022361793 -mv 1.08735022361793
u^9 2.12483412771106 2^u 2.12483412771106
```

And here's a [link containing the script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxljEEKwjAQRfc9xSerGUms7a6CJxFbFKoEmrSEZvT4ZqQb6Ww-8_6bCbigQ41pflHL1XNOEPiI63QPjzGtw5u8hWvqwNDSa0musTjx7VyhTC4vxs9CTvi3L8nHlYwYCzlG4j-aC81KLYwL6pALB-G92HdaluBNb3s9phI7m789fzJS&lang=sage) which runs on the SageMath server.

---

As I mentioned earlier, if you *don't* have access to the Lambert W function, you can calculate it using Newton's method. Of course, you can also use Newton's method to solve this equation directly. Here's one approach.

Our equation is
$$u = 9\log u / \log 2$$

We transform the equation to eliminate the $\log u$ term, so we don't get errors if $u\le 0$.

$$u \log 2 / 9 = \log u$$
Let $k = \log 2 / 9$
$$e^{uk} = u$$
Let
$$y = e^{uk} - u$$
so we want to find $u$ such that $y=0$.

Differentiating,
$$\frac{dy}{du} = ke^{uk} - 1$$
Now
$$\Delta u = \Delta y / \frac{dy}{du}$$
So
$$\Delta u = \frac{u - e^{uk}}{ke^{uk} - 1}$$
From a starting approximation of $u$, $u+\Delta u$ is a better approximation.

Here's some Sage / Python code which implements that algorithm. The code is mostly pure Python, it just uses Sage to input the initial approximation.

```
from math import exp, log
k = log(2) / 9

@interact
def main(u=1):
    for i in range(9):
        z = exp(u * k)
        du = (u - z) / (k * z - 1)
        u += du
        print(u, du)
        if abs(du) < 1e-12:
            break
```

#### Output

```
1.0873235056664654 0.08732350566646546
1.087350223615419 2.6717948953605787e-05
1.0873502236179315 2.5123282018144193e-12
1.0873502236179313 -2.4233897962905985e-16
```

Here's a [link containing the script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjtEKwjAMRd_7FfcxU4d0bxMH_krn2lnq2hFbkH29Kch2X0JObm7iOC1YTH7BL2viDPtdL3inWQUMtVLX4IpeqYeP2bJ5ZjVZJys-Uhl0c1MQucTw8BFs4myp_-OqTXIklApOCM2OpyJcYIutHqAg4006fVgKzoP49n5leYHKRdhh8g5m_JAg3KFtq7vjdNXI1oQftVw4eQ==&lang=python)

Answer (score 2):

Cubing, consider
$$f(x)=x-\frac{\log ^9(x)}{\log ^9(2)}$$
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{9 \log ^8(x)}{x \log ^9(2)}$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{9 (\log (x)-8) \log ^7(x)}{x^2 \log ^9(2)}$$
The first derivative cancels at two  points
$$x_{1,2}=\exp\Big[-8 W(\pm k) \Big]\qquad \qquad k=\frac{\log ^{\frac{9}{8}}(2)}{8 \sqrt[4]{3}}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function (numerically, $x_1=0.622419$ and $x_2=1.71274$).
$$f(x_1) \sim 0.655209 \qquad \qquad  f''(x_1)=+28.7147$$
$$f(x_2) \sim 1.610341 \qquad \qquad  f''(x_2)=-8.09651$$

So, $x_1$ corresponds to a minimum and $x_2$ to a maximum.

Now, by inspection, $f(2)=1$. So, using Newton method, the iterates will be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 2.00000 \\
 1 & 2.18208 \\
 2 & 2.13183 \\
 3 & 2.12495 \\
 4 & 2.12483
\end{array}
\right)$$
Then $f(x) >0$ for any $x < 2.12483$

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this? If not, take a look. Yes, there is no method to exactly compare them, unless you consider this special function $W_z(k)$, as a known function.

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E%281%2F3%29-log2%28x%29%5E3

If you refer to the behavior of log/power to infinity (i.e. for x sufficiently large), always the power $x^n, n>0$ goes faster to $\infty$ than $(log_mx)^p$, where $p,m>1$.