# Approximation for the Lambert $W$ function from $x=5$ to $x=105$

Tags: graphing-functions, approximation, lambert-w

Recently, I learnt about the Lambert $W$ function which is the inverse of $f(x) = x\cdot e^{x}$ and have been trying to solve problems related to it on the internet. After solving each problem, however, I find myself going back to WolframAlpha to calculate the result which is rather inconvenient. So I was wondering if I could find an approximation for $W(x)$ which I can simply plug into my standard calculator which is almost always close to me.

Playing around with the graph of $W(x)$ seemed like the most obvious method to me and so I began to try out different functions to match its graph. After a while, I settled upon $f(x) = 1.006 \log _{3.96} (x+1)$ from $x=5$ to $x=105$. From the graph of $g(x) = W(x) - 1.006 \log _{3.96} (x+1), x=5 \: \text{to} \: x=105$ on WolframAlpha, $f(x)$ seems to be within $ \approx\pm 0.02$ of $W(x)$. Is this a good approximation? If not, how can I make it better? Furthermore, is there a way to find a good approximation algebraically rather than graphically?

Comment: To make my last formula looking nicer, making the numers rational, use $$\frac{79}{102} \log \left(x+\frac{119}{52}\right)-\frac{33}{164}$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question but does $\log(x)$ here refer to $\log _{10} (x)$  or $\log _{e} (x)$ ?

Comment: There is no stupid question ! To tell the truth, I only know one logarithm : $\log_e(.)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you!

Comment: Here's a [Sage / Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNT0EOgjAQvPOKObYi2CIIMZL4E1NkMY2kksqh_N4WUJzbzszO7F61Gcmq-xi11OHGprrg5wgeDjWYSMsyzwuJHXrDJsTI0qyqjieOBCLNhJS55LN_sD6KuWXoXhYa2sAq8yAmxRoaQCGZ3PD1BrTUj8rTk491vozcT3KI61U_gFFQmecg-ba-du8X38brDqp5s4XFBZISmW2XBDSW1PP_gbk9HMc_hqtDkA==&lang=sage) which computes the Lambert W using Newton's method, using Claude's formula for the initial approximation.

Comment: Have a look at my edit ! $\color{red}{1000}$ times better !

Comment: @PM2Ring. Would you mind to use you script with a bunch of decimals with my last fromula  for much higher accuracy and post it separately ?  Thanks and cheers. :-)

Comment: @Claude [Here you go](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNT0FugzAQvPsVc7QTJ7XdGpwoSHlJKgN2hRqRyOEAv-8aaOmcZmd2Z3e9RC3RSLQSERU4gzoaWzj9LjN12p7cQu1HaZSZaVE6ZQqi-qhLY52STDB27fohJN8MrA0Rn3yqrDgzEEZK9tijxg73nk-3lopG4IY4-89Eo3wUcxEfCR26Hsn3X4FrtYZkhJwUxudvb0Yb7oMnecKBFu3I_rNG7KvVfwMP2eWkQYttfN0tl75N7yJ8_eKLigt0OGizXZJRp-C__z8wb8_HiR-Qtk9R&lang=sage)

Comment: @PM2Ring. Thanks ! Cheers :-)

Comment: BTW, Sage implements all branches of the [complex Lambert W function](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/log.html#sage.functions.log.Function_lambert_w). I used it in [this recent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3991940/207316)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the bounds

$$\log (x)-\log (\log (x))+\frac12\frac{\log (\log (x))}{ \log (x)} < W(x)$$
$$W(x)< \log (x)-\log (\log (x))+\frac e{e-1 }\frac{ \log (\log (x))}{ \log (x)}$$ for a specific range, we can numerically minimize
$$\Phi(k)=\int_a^b \Big[\log (x)-\log (\log (x))+k\frac{\log (\log (x))}{ \log (x)}-W(x)\Big]^2\,dx$$

For $a=5$ and $b=105$, this gives $k\sim 0.881076$ but the formula is a bit more complex than your.

Trying something of the same shape as your
$$W(x) \sim a+b \log_e(x+c)$$ a nonlinear regression gives $(R^2>0.999999)$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -0.201141 & 0.004453 & \{-0.209981,-0.192302\} \\
 b & +0.774451 & 0.000974 & \{+0.772518,+0.776385\} \\
 c & +2.288360 & 0.034073 & \{+2.220730,+2.356000\} \\
\end{array}$$ which leads to a maximum absolute error of $0.005$.

*Congratulations for your idea !*

**Edit**

Since we are using totally empirical models, let us try

$$W(x) \sim a+b \Big[\log_e(x^d+c)\Big]^f$$

$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.256813 & 0.001340 & \{0.254152,0.259474\} \\
 b & 0.815983 & 0.001525 & \{0.812955,0.819012\} \\
 c & 0.547202 & 0.001079 & \{0.545059,0.549345\} \\
 d & 0.678026 & 0.000656 & \{0.676723,0.679329\} \\
 f & 1.172580 & 0.000318 & \{1.171940,1.173210\} \\
\end{array}$$ which reduces the previous sum of squares by a factor close to $800,000$ (!!) and leads to a maximum absolute error equal to $5\times 10^{-6}$. Better, isn't it ?